Use 2 clip planes to create a slice and clearly see edges
In an OpenSceneGraph project, I have a box with a cylinder inside it. I pass 2 clipping planes through the box + cylinder model, each plane facing in the opposite direction. This results in a cross-sectional slice through the box.  I place the camera camera a distance away and face it at the slice in order to view the cross-section of the model.
With the camera facing perpendicular to the cross-section, the edges of both the box and the cylinder are not visible.  I have to move the camera at some angle to get the edges to show up.  Ultimately I want to move the camera along the length of the box and take successive images at this head-on angle in order to visualize cross-sections at successive locations, so I need the edges of both the box and the cylinder to clearly stand out.
I have tried setting the line width and color, but this doesn't solve my issue.
Other things I have tried:

Adding lighting from different angles
Removing back-culling
Enabling wireframe mode for the edges
Using a Scribe
Using the osgFX::Outline effect

The wireframe and scribe each offer a bit of an edge, but it is not very good (some pixels).  The osgFX Outline also creates a very thin edge, and these are all slightly enhanced by lighting.  But nothing produces a simple, clear, well-defined box and circle.
One other idea was to fill the cylinder with fog, which would have the effect and "filling" it with something that could be viewed when clipped.  However this didn't work for me (perhaps I was implementing the fog incorrectly).  I would also need two different colors / densities of fog to differentiate between the box and cylinder, and I'm not sure this would work.
Below is a running simple example of what I am working on.  If you run this program, you will see that the edges of the box and cylinder are completely invisible until the position of the camera is moved.
#include <osg/Shape>
#include <osg/ShapeDrawable>
#include <osg/Geode>
#include <osg/Material>
#include <osg/LineWidth>
#include <osgViewer/CompositeViewer>
#include <osg/PositionAttitudeTransform>
#include <osg/ClipNode>
#include <osg/ClipPlane>
#include <osgGA/TrackballManipulator>

const float BOX_LENGTH      = 240.0;
const float BOX_HEIGHT      =  20.0;
const float BOX_WIDTH       =  16.0;
const float CYL_RADIUS      =   0.5;
const float CAMERA_Y        = -1.0 * BOX_LENGTH/2;  //Where to start the camera
const float CAMERA_TO_CLIP  = 100.0;                 //Distance from camera to clip plane
const float SLICE_THICKNESS =  0.1;                  //The thickness of our slice
const int WIDTH =  600;  //Image dimensions
const int HEIGHT = 600;
const osg::Vec4 WHITE(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  //Create the box
  osg::ref_ptr<osg::Box> box = new osg::Box(osg::Vec3(0, 0, 0), BOX_WIDTH, BOX_LENGTH, BOX_HEIGHT);
  osg::ref_ptr<osg::ShapeDrawable> boxDrawable = new osg::ShapeDrawable(box);
  osg::ref_ptr<osg::Geode> boxGeode = new osg::Geode();
  boxGeode->addDrawable(boxDrawable);

  //Create the cylinder
  osg::ref_ptr<osg::Cylinder> cylinder = new osg::Cylinder(osg::Vec3(0, 0, 0), CYL_RADIUS, BOX_LENGTH);
  osg::ref_ptr<osg::ShapeDrawable> cylinderDrawable = new osg::ShapeDrawable(cylinder);
  osg::ref_ptr<osg::Geode> cylinderGeode = new osg::Geode();
  cylinderGeode->addDrawable(cylinderDrawable);

  //...and set the Line Width and Color
  osg::ref_ptr<osg::StateSet> stateSet = cylinderGeode->getOrCreateStateSet();
  osg::ref_ptr<osg::LineWidth> lineWidth = new osg::LineWidth(3.0f);  // Adjust line width
  stateSet->setAttributeAndModes(lineWidth, osg::StateAttribute::ON);
  osg::ref_ptr<osg::Material> material = new osg::Material;
  material->setDiffuse(osg::Material::FRONT_AND_BACK, WHITE);  
  stateSet->setAttributeAndModes(material, osg::StateAttribute::ON);
  
  //Put the cylinder in the box
  osg::ref_ptr<osg::PositionAttitudeTransform> cylinderTransform = new osg::PositionAttitudeTransform();
  cylinderTransform->setPosition(osg::Vec3(0, 0, 0));
  cylinderTransform->setAttitude(osg::Quat(osg::DegreesToRadians(90.0f), osg::Vec3(1, 0, 0))); // Rotate 90 degrees on x-axis
  cylinderTransform->addChild(cylinderGeode);

  osg::ref_ptr<osg::Group> model = new osg::Group();
  model->addChild(boxGeode);
  model->addChild(cylinderTransform);

  //Set up the View and viewer
  osg::ref_ptr<osgViewer::View> view = new osgViewer::View;
  view->setUpViewInWindow( 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT );
  view->getCamera()->setViewport(new osg::Viewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT));
  osgViewer::CompositeViewer viewer;
  viewer.addView(view);

  //Set up the manipulator so we can move the camera
  osg::ref_ptr<osgGA::CameraManipulator> cameraManip(new osgGA::TrackballManipulator());
  view->setCameraManipulator(cameraManip.get());
  
  //Set up where our camera is looking
  float camera_pos_y = CAMERA_Y;
  float center_pt_y = camera_pos_y + CAMERA_TO_CLIP;
  osg::Vec3d eye(0.0, camera_pos_y, 0.0);
  osg::Vec3d center(0, center_pt_y, 0);
  osg::Vec3d up(0, 0, 1);
  cameraManip->setHomePosition(eye, center, up);
  cameraManip->home(0.0);
    
  //Create a clipping plane through the middle of the model in the x-z plane
  float y_side1 =  1.0;      //Clip everything to the left  (keep everything to the right)
  float y_side2 = -1.0;      //Clip everything to the right (keep everything to the left)
  float y_offset1 = -1.0 * center_pt_y;
  float y_offset2 =        center_pt_y + SLICE_THICKNESS;
  osg::ref_ptr<osg::ClipPlane> clipPlane1 = new osg::ClipPlane(0, 0.0, y_side1, 0.0, y_offset1);
  osg::ref_ptr<osg::ClipPlane> clipPlane2 = new osg::ClipPlane(1, 0.0, y_side2, 0.0, y_offset2);

  //Attach the clipping planes
  osg::ref_ptr<osg::ClipNode> clipNode = new osg::ClipNode();
  clipNode->addClipPlane(clipPlane1);
  clipNode->addClipPlane(clipPlane2);
  clipNode->addChild(model);

  //Root node
  osg::ref_ptr<osg::Group> root(new osg::Group);
  root->addChild(clipNode);

  //Ensure the clipping plane is enabled
  root->getOrCreateStateSet()->setMode(GL_CLIP_PLANE0, osg::StateAttribute::ON);
  root->getOrCreateStateSet()->setMode(GL_CLIP_PLANE1, osg::StateAttribute::ON);

  view->setSceneData(root);
  viewer.run();
  
  return 0;
}

